Change of coordinates on $\nabla(h\circ\varphi^{-1})$ where $h,\varphi:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$
Say I have a smooth vector-valued function $h:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and a smooth diffeomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider the gradient of the composition $h\circ\varphi^{-1}$, namely $\nabla(h\circ\varphi^{-1}).$ Now suppose I want to do a change of variables and express the gradient $\nabla(h\circ\varphi^{-1})$ in terms of the new variable $y:=\varphi^{-1}(x).$ Of course I cannot simply write $\nabla h(y)$ since this doesn't account for the action of $\nabla.$ I believe that
\begin{align}
\nabla(h\circ\varphi^{-1})&=\left((\nabla^\top h_1\circ\varphi^{-1})(\nabla\varphi^{-1}),\dots,(\nabla^\top h_n\circ\varphi^{-1})(\nabla\varphi^{-1})\right)^\top=\left(\nabla^\top h_1(y)(\nabla\varphi^{-1}),\dots,\nabla^\top h_n(y)(\nabla\varphi^{-1})\right)^\top.
\end{align}
So now it seems that the problem becomes expressing the Jacobian $\nabla\varphi^{-1}$ in terms of $y$, which is to say that I just need to express the partial derivatives $\partial\varphi_i^{-1}/\partial x_j$ in terms of $y_k$, but I am failing to see how to do this simple thing. For simplicity, take $n=2$. Then $y_1=\varphi_1^{-1}(x_1,x_2)$ and $y_2=\varphi_2^{-1}(x_1,x_2)$. This leads me to use the chain rule (thinking of the $y_i=y_i(x_1,x_2)$) for something like
$$\frac{\partial\varphi_1^{-1}}{\partial x_1}=\frac{\partial\varphi_1^{-1}}{\partial y_1}\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_1}+\frac{\partial\varphi_1^{-1}}{\partial y_2}\frac{\partial y_2}{\partial x_1},$$
but this doesn't seem to help me get rid of the old coordinates $x_1,x_2$. $\textbf{What am I doing wrong?}$ $\textbf{What am I thinking about incorrectly?}$

What do you mean by the gradient in this case? The gradient is only defined for differentiable maps $h:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, but the codomain of your map is $\mathbb{R}^n$. Maybe you mean the derivative of $h$ instead?

@FernandoNazario The gradient is not just defined for scalar-valued functions. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#Gradient_of_a_vector_field and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_derivative_%28continuum_mechanics%29#Gradient_of_a_tensor_field

@FernandoNazario Gradient of a function $h:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ in coordinates is just the Jacobian.

Your notation suffers from a number of problems.

(the least severe) $\varphi^{-1}$ can be replaced by the diffeomorphism $\psi$ to simplify notation

(much more severe) the notation $\nabla$ does not make it clear w.r.t. which variables $x_i$ or $y_i$ you differentiate. I suggest to use
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\,,\quad\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}
$$
or more briefly
$$
\partial_{x_i}\,,\quad\partial_{y_i}\,.
$$

With the notation
$$\psi(x)=y$$
and each $h_j$ being a function of $y_1,...,y_n$
the chain rule gives
$$
\partial_{x_i}h_j(\psi(x))=\sum_{k=1}^n(\partial_{y_k}h_j)(\psi(x))\;\partial_{x_i}\psi_k(x)
$$
or more briefly
$$
\partial_{x_i}(h_j\circ\psi)=\sum_{k=1}^n((\partial_{y_k}h_j)\circ\psi)\;\partial_{x_i}\psi_k\,.
$$
This can be recognized as the matrix multiplication of the Jacobian of
$h$ evaluated at $\psi$
with the Jacobian of $\psi\,.$ This matrix product gives the Jacobian
of $h\circ\psi\,.$

You write that you want to express $
\partial_{x_i}(h_j\circ\psi)$ (the Jacobian of $h\circ\psi$) in the new variable $y\,.$ But you can't because it is not a function of $y$ - unlike the Jacobian of $h\,.$


